# Solving $y'(x) = \frac{y(x)}{3x-y^2(x)}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving $y'(x) = \frac{y(x)}{3x-y^2(x)}$ ? I'm trying to solve this first order non-linear equation. I've tried to plug in a couple of different things and would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y}{3x-y^2}\implies \dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{3x-y^2}{y}\implies \dfrac{dx}{dy}= \left(\dfrac{3}{y}\right)x-y$

Comment: I feel like this is correct, but all I see is now I have to solve for $\frac{1}{y'}$, and I'm lost again.

Comment: @John: Notice that the equation is linear in $x$. Also see [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcollege.cengage.com%2Fmathematics%2Flarson%2Fcalculus_early%2F3e%2Fshared%2Fchapter15%2Fclc7eap1502.pdf&ei=8FNxVLHgFNaUuATP6YGgCw&usg=AFQjCNHxp2mjiIqPx7M-Fg4bsz2C9Zib2Q&bvm=bv.80185997,d.c2E).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint;**

Rewrite as $$y(x)-(y^2(x)-3x)y'(x)=0$$ then divide both sides by $y^4(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain one solution if you apply a trial solution of the form $y=Ax^n$, which gives  $y=\pm \sqrt{x}$. You can also try to find an implicit solution, since you have to solve

$$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{3x-y^2}{y} $$

which is linear in $x$, therefore easy to solve. It has the solution

$$ x = y^2 + C_0 y^3 $$

In the special case of $C_0=0$ you get $y=\pm \sqrt{x}$. In the general case you can express $y$ using the formula of cubic polynomials

$$ y = \frac{1}{3C_0} \left[ \sqrt[3]{\frac{27 C_0^2 x + \sqrt{(27 C_0^2x-2)^2-4}-2}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{27 C_0^2 x + \sqrt{(27 C_0^2x-2)^2-4}-2}} -1\right]$$